# What is this font from Pacman?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm looking for what font this is:

[image]

A fair-use download would be ideal.

Comment: Font Squirrel Matcherator will find that font automatically. Just upload the image.

Answer (score 1):

It's [Whimsy TT Regular](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/gary-david-bouton/whimsy) which can be downloaded for free.

[image]